# Linux - Wired network drops out regularly until reset

Tags: linux-mint, network-adapter

Ever since upgrading to a new motherboard, I've been having issues with the wired network dropping out every hour or so. When I reset the network adapter (ifdown/ifup or through NetworkManager) it works again for some time.

I suspected the on-board RTL8111 network adapter so I purchased an Intel Gigabit CT adapter, but the issue is present with that as well.

It seems to drop out more quickly when I use more data, but I haven't been able to get evidence on that.

Some system info from `inxi -Fxz`:

```
System:
  Host: [host] Kernel: 5.3.0-40-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc 
  v: 7.4.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.4.8 Distro: Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia 
  base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASRock model: B450 Pro4 serial:  
  UEFI: American Megatrends v: P1.50 date: 11/05/2018 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel 82574L Gigabit Network driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k 
  port: e000 bus ID: 22:00.0 
  IF: enp34s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac:  
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  vendor: ASRock driver: r8169 v: kernel port: c000 bus ID: 25:00.0 
  IF: enp37s0 state: down mac:
```

I've already reinstalled NetworkManager, removed and added my network profiles. What else can I try?

Comment: Update the BIOS and the LAN driver on this machine to see if that improves the situation. It certainly is abnormal to have the LAN adapter drop out every hour or so.

Comment: @John I'm on the latest BIOS and I've tried different drivers for the Realtek network adapter, but as I said even with a new PCI network card the issues persists. I suspect the issue might be on a different layer.

Comment: Is there a warranty on the motherboard?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how that is relevant.

Comment: If the new(ish) motherboard is causing the issue (and you replace the Network cards) then I am thinking the motherboard might be the issue.

Comment: I don't think so, after adding a secondary network card it's more likely there's some issue in the OS.